# How to push code to different projects repos?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I'm working for 3 different clients now and I need to push the code to they repos. I was thinking that if I change the working directory it allow me to set new remote origin. But after executing this command `git remote` I see the old remote.

How to set different remotes for different clients?
Thank you in advance!

P.S I have one account on bitbucket with privileges to read and write to clients repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one remote for each client

```
git remote add client1 path-to-repo-client1
git remote add client2 path-to-repo-client2
# then you can do stuff
git push client1 branch-client1
git push client2 branch-client2
```